# Unable to get Resource in FLOWS

Tags: visual-workflow, trailhead

I am doing Trailhead  -"**Build a Simple Flow**"

In third Section-***Branch the Flow***:

I am not getting Select value for Resource as highlighted 
[image]

Also i m sure update toggle is there as i have passed previous section of trail

Infact there is a Note has been added in trail:-
Note
You can’t copy and paste the Resource values. For the first condition, type update_to into Resource, click on update_toggle >, then select Value. For the second condition, type Find into Resource, click on Contact from Find_a_Match >, then click in the blank space below.

Correct Snapshot as shown in trailhead

[image]

Comment: Do you have an underscore in there? Try typing `update_tog` and go from there. Looks like you might have put in a period instead.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it you have to uncheck Manually assign variables (advanced) in the toggle that you have created

Answer (score 1):

1. go to screen( Contact Info)  -> click Toggle -> scroll down the menu of toggle -> "Uncheck" Manually assign variables (advanced).
2. open decision -> click "add condition" enter update_toggle @ resource -> value.  ;)